# Calculate sd and mean for many data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, mean

I have data frames called bmw_1,bmw_2,....bmw_9 and I want to calculate standard deviation and mean for each data frame but I don’t want to write

mean(bmw_1)
mean(bmw_2)
mean(bmw_3)
...
mean(bmw_9)

many times, so any help please

Comment: Are you ok for writing `list(bmw_1, ..., bmw_9)`?

Comment: Actually I have bmw_1,...,bmw_100, so I want to use a Loop to change the number.

Comment: I used something like


for (j in 1:100) {
  mean(bmw_[j])
}

but it didn’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comment, best way is to get the data frames into a list so you can apply a function over each.

Get all dfs into a list by name pattern:

```
ls_bmw <- mget(ls(pattern = "bmw_"))
```

Then apply the mean.

```
result <- lapply(ls_bmw, mean)
```

Difficult to go much further without a data example, but to get the results alongside the data frame name use:

```
 names(ls_bmw)
```

... to get a vector of the df names and:

```
 unlist(result)
```

... to get a vector of the results. The order of names and results elements will match and you convert that into a single result dataframe.